# How can I use JBoss connection pooling with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, jboss5.x

How can I use JBoss connection pooling with Spring MVC? A tutorial would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You just define a data source, and JBoss automagically handles the connection pooling for you:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee.html#connector-j-usagenotes-jboss